# orientability of the möbius strip using homology

Tags: geometry, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I read in Hatcher's "Algebraic topology" book about orientability of topological maifolds using homology. now I would like to know how one can apply this to show that the möbius strip is not orientable? i have no idea.

Comment: A connected $n$-manifold is orientable iff $H_n(M,\partial M)\cong\mathbb Z$.

Comment: how can one prove this? or is it in hatcher's book, at whic page?

Comment: See Theorem 3.43 of Hatcher.

Comment: @Jim - Surely this should be an answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

One can show that a connected $n$-manifold is orientable iff $H_n(M,\partial M)\cong \mathbb Z$. Theorem 3.43 of Hatcher gives the "only if" direction. Namely, if $M$ is orientanble, then $H_n(M,\partial M)\cong H^0(M)\cong \mathbb Z$. So to show that the Möbius strip is not orientable, it suffices to show $H_2(M,\partial M)=0$.